# How to choose Jupyter syntax highlighting language

Tags: jupyter-notebook, syntax-highlighting, jupyter-lab

I regularly read and edit `.cu` files (cuda) in Jupyter. Is there a way to get Jupyter to use C++ syntax highlighting for `.cu` files? (They are basically C++ files)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a JupyterLab extension ([guide](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_dev.html), [tutorial](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extension/extension_points.html)), there are some examples out there like  `jupyterlab_robotmode` ([this](https://github.com/MarketSquare/jupyterlab_robotmode/blob/d5bd3a3a4a49f6019d17d6d9ab25c4c54acd4e7f/src/plugin.ts#L22-L29) and [this](https://github.com/MarketSquare/jupyterlab_robotmode/blob/d5bd3a3a4a49f6019d17d6d9ab25c4c54acd4e7f/src/mode.ts#L650-L673) part) and this [comment](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10095#issuecomment-819889990). You will want to reuse CodeMirror's [clike](https://codemirror.net/mode/clike/) mode, probably incorporating [these c++ bits](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/d60fff6750cd4963ebfd83d446d5bd3ad6b083a3/mode/clike/clike.js#L440-L478). It would roughly look like this:

```js
import { JupyterFrontEnd, JupyterFrontEndPlugin } from '@jupyterlab/application';
import { ICodeMirror } from '@jupyterlab/codemirror';


const extension: JupyterFrontEndPlugin<void> = {
  id: 'jupyterlab-cuda-mode',
  autoStart: true,
  requires: [ICodeMirror],
  activate: (app: JupyterFrontEnd, codeMirrorToken: ICodeMirror) => {
    const cm = codeMirrorToken.CodeMirror as any;
    cm.defineMIME(
      "text/x-cuda",
      {
        name: "clike",
        // add more configuration below
        namespaceSeparator: "::",
        modeProps: {fold: ["brace", "include"]}
      }
    );
    // add more keywords
    cm.registerHelper('hintWords', 'text/x-cuda', {'__global__': true});
    cm.modeInfo.push({
      ext: ["cu"],
      mime: "text/x-cuda",
      mode: "clike",
      name: "cuda"
    });
  }
};

export default extension;
```

Now  if you also want to have nice icon in the lanucher you would need to register it with the [`DocumentRegistry`](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/classes/docregistry.documentregistry-1.html) like the builtin file types are [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/fed7ed2e331a88da0c5c92c1833dfa08fc09c22c/packages/docregistry/src/registry.ts#L1446-L1451)

Of note, JupyterLab 4.0 and Jupyter Notebook 7.0 will use CodeMirror 6 which has a reworked parser. The old modes will still be supported via a legacy shim, but if you are thinking about developing a new mode, you might want to target lazer parser from CodeMirror 6.

Comment: Thanks, but wow! This looks pretty involved. I was hoping to do this by modifying a config file here and there, since C++ syntax highlighting already works.

Comment: I agree, it could be just a simple mapping in the Settings which would help a lot of simple use cases (though defining a dedicated mode will be always better). There is an feature request to enable it already open here: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/4223. If anyone would like to contribute, I am happy to guide them and review the pull request.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way without any extension can be using Markdown in Jupyter Notebook and [Markdown Syntax Highlighting](https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#syntax-highlighting). You can use it for most of the languages but a drawback of this, you cannot see highlighting while you are editing code, just you can see after run. If your purpose is to see highlighted code between other blocks then it is useful. An example usage:

````
```c++

// your code goes here

```
````

Then, run markdown block.

Comment: It appears that when saving a notebook (in Jupyter Lab) as a .html, the syntax highlighting reverts to Python even with the c++ magic - do you know of any fixes?

Comment: @chrysaor4 Maybe saving as `LaTeX` then converting to `html` can solve your problem.